# C# add class from file without recompiling

Tags: c#

For a programming class I need to write a plugin-manager that can handle PlugIns (store them and assign requests to them that they need to handle) that implement a certain Interface (IPlugin). I've done this and so far it works out.

Additionally the plugin-manager needs to be able to handle/add 3rd party plugins without recompiling the whole programm. It is allowed to restart the programm.

Our professor suggested to us, that when restarting the project the pluginmanager should look for already compiled classes that implement IPlugin in a certain folder and add them to the list of active plugins.

As I haven't found anything on the internet to help me yet I would like to know if somebody knows how to do it?

Comment: look for `MEF`, and `Dependency Injection`.

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Load the assemblies in the target directory and scan the types to identify every type implementing your plugin interface.

Comment: As Amy suggested. Load the assemblies in the directory (DLL's, EXE's) using Reflection. Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx and read the Remarks section to understand what it's trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `System.Reflection` namespace. It contains the `Assembly` class which is necessary for loading .NET assemblies in run-time. But be warned, if you load a non .NET assembly it will throw a `BadImageFormatException`.

When the assembly is loaded you can fetch all public types with the `GetExportedTypes` method provided by the Assembly class. You'ld have to filter them to check if they `IPlugin` is assignable from the type and if it has an agreed-upon constructor, e.g. an empty default constructor.

Then you can create an instance of the type by either calling `Invoke` on the `ConstructorInfo` object or simpler by using the `Activator` class. Both ways you have to cast the created object to `IPlugin`. The last step would be using the methods and properties provided by the interface to initialize the plugin.

As a bonus you can make use of the `FileSystemWatcher` from the `System.IO` namespace to watch for files created in a specified folder. You can subscribe to the `Created` event to then load assemblies. You have to watch out, the `FileSystemWatcher` does not invoke the event if the property `EnableRaisingEvents` is set to false - which it is by default.

I'll provide you with an example, but encourage you to try to implement your own version first.

```
    private void LoadAssembly(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find the file \"{path}\"");

        try
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
            foreach (IPlugin plugin in asm.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(type => typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(type) &&
                               type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                .Select(type => Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPlugin))
            {
                plugin.Load();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (
            ex is FileLoadException ||
            ex is BadImageFormatException)
        {
            // Do something useful
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer :) I will try it out tomorrow and report here if it worked out for me